# Deploying app fails with nginx and react/django

Tags: reactjs, django, nginx

I've been trying to deploy a React+Django app in development but without success.
So everything works fine locally using Django's `python3 manage.py runserver`

In deployment, I am using gunicorn+nginx. When I set gunicorn and test it everything works fine.
However, when I add nginx on top, the website works but it has lots of bugs, server calls fall 1 in 3 times, and the app is not stable. For example, I have a counter to count the numebr of visits in each page and it just keeps giving the sums of different combinations of visits each time I change the page, in short, the app is not stable.

Here is my nginx configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myip;
    client_max_body_size 700m;
    client_body_buffer_size 16k;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /path/to/app;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /path/to/app;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp.sock;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp.sock;
    }
}
```

Here is my `gunicorn.service` file

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/myapp/bin/gunicorn \
           --access-logfile - --workers 3 --timeout 60000 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp.sock myapp.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I tried increasing timeout time and client size because I thought it could be a bandwith issue, but that did not work.

I have no clue what's going on. Does nginx have to be configured specifically to allow React's `api/` urls?

UPDATE

Do I have to serve the REACT app on a different port (8000 for example) and then specify it on my /api construct in nginx configuration?